# How to obtain the location of proxy server

Tags: windows-7, proxy, windows-registry, regedit

I am trying to follow the guide [here](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/configuration/use-winxp-with-proxy.html) to set up the proxy so I can do `conda install` behind a proxy. But the automatic configuration script is greyed out so I can't copy its path. How do I obtain it's value via another way e.g. via registry?

I am using Windows 7 and I have admin rights.

[image]

Comment: Are those settings possible set by a domain administrator?

Comment: i got around it by ibstalling Python packages manually

Answer (score 1):

Under registry item:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE>SOFTWARE>POLICIES>INTERNET EXPLORER>CONTROL PANEL

there were **AutoConfig** Reg_DWord 1, and **Proxy** REG_DWord 1.

If these are set to 1 they grey out both options and the user whether an administrator or not cannot change them.  This prevent a novice user from messing up the selections.

Please delete both of these reg_dwords and the options should be then changeable.